# Mapping JIRA issue fields with Gitlab Issue

Tags: gitlab, jira, issue-tracking

I am migrating my issues from JIRA to Gitlab. I am using a CSV file for that purpose. But I am only able to map the Title and Description fields. Is there any way to map all other JIRA Issue fields with the one in GitLab Issues.

Here is a Sample CSV data:

```
title,description
My Issue Title,My Issue Description
Another Title,"A description, with a comma"
"One More Title","One More Description"
```

I want to include all other fields in my GitLab issues while importing the JIRA issues from CSV file. Along with Issue type, Assignee, Status(Closed/Open) etc.